# control line spacing in a label in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

i want to control the line spacing in a label of a node in tikz. In my example it's too big (between the two lines), I want to reduce it. I've already read things about line spacing inside a node, but not inside a label of a node.

Thanks,
J.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm]  

  \node[state,accepting][label={[align=center, inner sep=1ex]below: {\tiny{parameter:10}\\ \tiny{if $s_1=1$} }}] (q0)      {$s_0$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Your example throws an error here, but adding a `text width` to the label fixed that.)

You're using `\tiny` wrong, it's supposed be used like `{\tiny ..}`, not `\tiny{...}`,  i.e. it is a switch that affects the following text, not a macro that takes an argument. That said, I recommend adding `font=\tiny` to the `label` options instead. This also makes the line spacing more reasonable.

To further control the line spacing you can use the optional argument to `\\`, e.g. `\\[1cm]` to add an extra 1cm of vertical space.

Also, use `align=flush center` to avoid the stretching of the second line.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm]  
\node[state,accepting,label={[align=flush center, inner sep=1ex, text width=1.5cm,font=\tiny]below: parameter:10\\ if $s_1=1$ }] (q0)      {$s_0$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Indeed, I did not think of textwidth.

Comment: +1, but... the $s_1=1$ looks really stretched out. Do you know why?

Comment: @Rmano Has to do with how `align=center` is defined I think, read section 17.4.3 *Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text* in the manual. Reducing the text width helps, but easier to just set `align=flush center` instead of `center`.